# Cannot build prod version of angular application due to some library

Tags: angular, webpack, semantic-ui, angular2-aot

I added some library (ng2-semantic-ui) to my angular project and now when I build production version of application I got a lot of errors from this library.

```
(1,1): Directive SuiSearch, Property '_searchClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearch<T>'.
(1,1): Directive SuiSearch, Property '_searchClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearch<T>'.
(1,1): Directive SuiSearch, Property 'onFocusIn' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearch<T>'.
(1,1): Directive SuiSearch, Property 'onFocusOut' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearch<T>'.
node_modules/ng2-semantic-ui/dist/modules/search/components/search.d.ts.SuiSearch.html(12,5): Directive SuiSearchResult, Property '_optionClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearchResult<T>'.
(1,1): Directive SuiSearchResult, Property '_optionClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiSearchResult<T>'.
(1,1): Directive SuiPagination, Property '_paginationClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiPagination'.
(1,1): Directive SuiPagination, Property '_paginationClasses' is private and only accessible within class 'SuiPagination'.
```

I found also reported bug in this library: https://github.com/edcarroll/ng2-semantic-ui/issues/432

Is it possible to ignore this problems in webpack configuration? Is it correct that webpack compile this library?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how your are declaring the library, but this might be a duplicate of:
[Property 'X' is private and only accessible within class 'xyzComponent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141576/property-x-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-xyzcomponent)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11422

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem is diffrent, because comes from external library not from my code and I cannot simply change visibility of this fields. 

I added dependency in package.json import module in home.module.ts:

`import { SuiModule } from 'ng2-semantic-ui/dist';
imports: [SuiModule]
`
and then I used some component on my view...Nothing special about usage of this :)