# ERROR in node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal-header.d.ts.ModalHeaderComponent.html(3,107): Property 'modal' is private and it only accessible

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have encoutered and error which is it works perfectly fine in development but in production it throws an error

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal-header.d.ts.ModalHeaderComponent.html(3,107): Property 'modal' is private and only accessible within class 'ModalHeaderComponent'.
node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal-footer.d.ts.ModalFooterComponent.html(4,107): Property 'modal' is private and only accessible within class 'ModalFooterComponent'.
node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal/components/modal-footer.d.ts.ModalFooterComponent.html(5,86): Property 'modal' is private and only accessible within class 'ModalFooterComponent'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141576/property-x-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-xyzcomponent

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to watch this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11422, it may be useful