# Angular service interprets method as a property?

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have created an Angular service for my Angular component, `LiveDashboardComponent`, with a method to instantiate the component's property.

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { LiveDashboardService } from './live-dashboard.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'c8y-live-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'live-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['live-dashboard.component.less'],
})
export class LiveDashboardComponent {
   days: string[] | undefined;

  constructor(private liveDashboardService: LiveDashboardService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDays();
  }

  private getDays(): void {
    this.days = this.liveDashboardService.getDays();
  }
  
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class LiveDashboardService {
  private days: string[] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
  
  constructor() {}
  
  private getDays(): string[] {
    return this.days.slice();
  }
  
}
```

I am having a problem whereby the compiler underlines the getDays method *name*, meaning that it does not include the parenthesis `()`, in my component's implementation of the method with the following message.

```
Property 'getDays' is private and only accessible within class 'LiveDashboardService'
```

However, as the code snippet demonstrates, I do not have a property called `getDays` in my Angular service. Instead, it is a method, and I do not know why the compiler cannot identify it as such.

Comment: Methods are properties which are functions (according to JavaScript).

Comment: are you concerned about what `getDays` is called, not about the error itself? It's called a property because it is a property (with a function value), that you just happen to call a "method". Regardless of whether it is a function or another value, it's not accessible from the outside (because it's marked private) hence the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property 'X' is private and only accessible within class 'xyzComponent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141576/property-x-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-xyzcomponent)

Comment: Please at least do a cursory search for the error message before asking the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit, you can't call a private method from the outside : make it public

```
  public getDays(): string[] {
    return this.days.slice();
  }
```

Comment: Alright, that's a what I suspected. The code had been working for weeks and I am not sure why all of a sudden it's checking for this error.

Thanks