# How should I deal with this error on ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

```
index.js:493 [webpack-dev-server] ERROR  
src/app/home/home.page.html:12:27 - error TS2341: Property 'res' is private and only accessible within class 'HomePage'.

12     <span class="date">{{ res.current.dt}}</span>
                             ~~~

  src/app/home/home.page.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomePage.
```

I was trying to get data from the API to display on my html but it gives me this error and when I make the rome the "private" it doesn't get the data at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access private member in your template which is not right as for given component all its members (methods, properties) accessed by its template must be public.

This link might be helpful for you. [Property 'X' is private and only accessible within class 'xyzComponent'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141576/property-x-is-private-and-only-accessible-within-class-xyzcomponent)